# Python | Selenium cannot detect button

Tags: python, html, css, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os

Game_Pin = input('Enter your PIN: ')
NickNAME = input('Enter your nickname: ')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe")

def Enter_Press(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Enter')]").click()

def OK_GO(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'OK, go!')]").click()


def Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME, driver):
    driver.get('https://kahoot.it/')
    driver.maximize_window() #For maximizing window
    driver.implicitly_wait(2) #gives an implicit wait for 2 seconds

    game_pin = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='inputSession']")
    game_pin.send_keys(Game_Pin)
    Enter_Press(driver)

    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='username']")
    Name.send_keys(NickNAME)
    OK_GO(driver)




Kahoot_Spammer(Game_Pin, NickNAME, driver)
```

This is the code. Its supposed to open a chrome browser and navigate to the Kahoot.it website. Then take what information you gave it and put it in for you. It works for the first part of entering a game but once it gets to create your nickname it cannot detect the OK, go! button.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'OK, go!')]").click()
```

I've inspected the button but cannot seem to find what to put within the code above. Any ideas?

Here is the source code.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie10" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Kahoot!</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" media="(device-height: 568px)"/>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1131203560">

  <meta name="description" content="Join a game of kahoot here. Kahoot! is a free game-based learning platform that makes it fun to learn – any subject, in any language, on any device, for all ages!">
  <meta name="keywords" content="education, platform, smart phone, tablet, mobile, social, inclusive, HTML5, classroom, engagement, play, game, fun, quiz, multi-player, pedagogy, learning model, learn, gamification." />


  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/shared/theme/kahoot/img/icons/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/shared/theme/kahoot/img/icons/touch_icon_144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/shared/theme/kahoot/img/icons/touch_icon_114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/shared/theme/kahoot/img/icons/touch_icon_72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/shared/theme/kahoot/img/icons/touch_icon_57.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/shared/css/cloak.css">

  <div style="height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; visibility: hidden">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><filter x="-2.2%" y="-2.3%" width="104.4%" height="104.8%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a"><feOffset dy="1" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1"/><symbol id="logo-shapes" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><ellipse cx="5.506" cy="18.966" rx="4.953" ry="4.953"/><path d="M12.005 5.902L17.873.033l5.869 5.869-5.869 5.868zm1.443 8.899h8.849v8.849h-8.849zm-2.584-4.977H.146l5.36-8.555z"/></symbol></svg>
  </div>

  <script src="https://tap-nexus.appspot.com/js/sdk/kahunaAPI_min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(e,t){var n=e.amplitude||{_q:[],_iq:{}};var r=t.createElement("script");r.type="text/javascript";
    r.async=true;r.src="https://d24n15hnbwhuhn.cloudfront.net/libs/amplitude-3.4.0-min.gz.js";
    r.onload=function(){e.amplitude.runQueuedFunctions()};var i=t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    i.parentNode.insertBefore(r,i);function s(e,t){e.prototype[t]=function(){this._q.push([t].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)));
    return this}}var o=function(){this._q=[];return this};var a=["add","append","clearAll","prepend","set","setOnce","unset"];
    for(var u=0;u<a.length;u++){s(o,a[u])}n.Identify=o;var c=function(){this._q=[];return this;
    };var p=["setProductId","setQuantity","setPrice","setRevenueType","setEventProperties"];
    for(var l=0;l<p.length;l++){s(c,p[l])}n.Revenue=c;var d=["init","logEvent","logRevenue","setUserId","setUserProperties","setOptOut","setVersionName","setDomain","setDeviceId","setGlobalUserProperties","identify","clearUserProperties","setGroup","logRevenueV2","regenerateDeviceId","logEventWithTimestamp","logEventWithGroups"];
    function v(e){function t(t){e[t]=function(){e._q.push([t].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)));
    }}for(var n=0;n<d.length;n++){t(d[n])}}v(n);n.getInstance=function(e){e=(!e||e.length===0?"$default_instance":e).toLowerCase();
    if(!n._iq.hasOwnProperty(e)){n._iq[e]={_q:[]};v(n._iq[e])}return n._iq[e]};e.amplitude=n;
    })(window,document);
  </script>

  <base href="/">

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<scri'+'pt ');
    document.write('type="text/javascript" ');
    document.write('src="'+'/shared/theme/config.js');
    document.write("?"+new Date().getTime()+'">');
    document.write('</scri'+'pt>');
  </script>
</head>
<body snitch ios7-viewport-fix>
  <noscript>
    <h1>Kahoot! needs JavaScript to work</h1>

    <p>
      To use Kahoot!, you need to have JavaScript enabled in your browser. To enable JavaScript, please do the following:
    </p>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="http://enable-javascript.com/">Follow these instructions</a>.</li>
      <li>Make sure you have the <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/">latest browser</a>.</li>
      <li>Turn off or disable the NoScript extension, if you have it.</li>
      <li>Contact your IT administrator to allow access to Kahoot! in your security preferences.</li>
    </ul>

    <p>If you continue to have problems, please let us know by <a href="http://kahoot.uservoice.com/">contacting Kahoot! support</a>.</p>
  </noscript>
  <div id="debug-info" debug-info="dev,test" debug-timestamp></div>
  <dev-mode></dev-mode>

  <div class="loader" loader></div>

  <iframe
    id="gameBlockIframe"
    style="display:none;"
    class="game-block-iframe"
    sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
    scrolling="no">
  </iframe>

  <div id="mainView" ng-cloak ng-view>
    <h1>Join in a Kahoot! here</h1>
    <p>To learn more about Kahoot! visit <a href="https://kahoot.com/?utm_source=controller&utm_campaign=controller_app" target="_system">kahoot.com</a></p>
  </div>

  <div ng-cloak alerts></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

function gup( name, url ) {
    if (!url) url = location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
    var results = regex.exec( url );
    return results == null ? null : results[1];
}



var clientId = gup('gaId', window.location.search);

if (clientId) {
  ga('create', 'UA-35308575-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true, 'clientId':gup('gaId', window.location.search)});
  ga('create', 'UA-35308575-4', 'auto', {'name': 'legacy', 'clientId':gup('gaId', window.location.search)});
  var platform = gup('platform', window.location.search);

  if (typeof platform === 'string' && platform == 'iOS') {
          window.ga('set', 'appName', 'Kahoot');
          window.ga('set', 'appId', 'no.mobitroll.kahoot.controller');
        }
  if (typeof platform === 'string' && platform == 'Android') {
          window.ga('set', 'appName', 'Kahoot');
          window.ga('set', 'appId', 'no.mobitroll.kahoot.android');
        }
} else {
  ga('create', 'UA-35308575-1', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
  ga('create', 'UA-35308575-4', 'auto', {'name': 'legacy'});
}


  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('legacy.send', 'pageview');

  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not how `implicitly_wait` works. In your case, you are better off using `time.sleep`

Answer (score 0):

`implicitly_wait` needs to only be declared **once** when `driver` is initialized. To explicitly wait a specified number of seconds, you may use `time.sleep()`, although the more practical solution is just dynamically wait for the element to be present/clickable using Selenium's [`WebDriverWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).